# Integration Spotify sdk with other framework

Tags: ios, xcode, spotify

I'm trying to include the Spotify downloaded from the official github.
I copy / paste in my project.

However I can't import Spotify library.

I think it's due with my cocoapods library which have been installed with this corrsponding podfile:

```
use_frameworks!

target 'ApplicationTest' do
pod 'Facebook-iOS-SDK', '~> 3.21'    
pod 'MBProgressHUD', '~> 0.9.1'
end
```

In the "Other Linker Flags" I have : -ObjC -framework "FBSDKLoginKit" etc..

I don't know what to do to use Spotify library

Comment: You didn't mention if you are using Objective-C or Swift. [If you are following Spotify's "Beginner's Tutorial"](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/spotify-ios-sdk/tutorial/), which step did you get stuck on?  If you're not using that tutorial, what are you following in order to get things set up?

Comment: Sorry. I'm using Swift. Everything works fine from step 1 to 9 from the tutorial. But when I begin to write the code, SPTAuth is not recognized.
These are my steps: 1- DL and copy/paste the official spotify sdk, 2- Check in General Tab that Spotify framework is included (ok), 3- Check in Build Settings / Other Linker Flags that I have -Objc (ok). But when I start to code it didn't recognize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import the Spotify.h header file via your app's bridging header.

If you already have a bridging header in your project, simply add to it:

```
#import <Spotify/Spotify.h>
```

Comment: Ok thanks. I was a bit confusing with swift , objC libraries so I didn't think that I can use the bridging header while in podfile I'm using the use_frameworks! line.